# Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rvm, rmagick

```
$ gem install rmagick
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/bin:/Users/XXXXXXX/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/XXXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

But when I do this:

```
$ locate Magick-config
/opt/local/bin/Magick-config
/opt/local/share/man/man1/Magick-config.1.gz
/opt/local/var/macports/software/ImageMagick/6.6.4-9_0+q16/opt/local/bin/Magick-config
/opt/local/var/macports/software/ImageMagick/6.6.4-9_0+q16/opt/local/share/man/man1/Magick-config.1.gz
/opt/local/var/macports/software/ImageMagick/6.6.5-0_0+q16/opt/local/bin/Magick-config
/opt/local/var/macports/software/ImageMagick/6.6.5-0_0+q16/opt/local/share/man/man1/Magick-config.1.gz
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, missed the second part of your question.  I'm not sure how you specify the path to imagemagick when installing the gem.  macports puts things in non-standard locations, so it's not seeing it.

Comment: had same problem in terminal do export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH  then sudo gem install rmagick works fine

Comment: @Rubytastic: this is the only thing that got it to work.  I noticed that the PATH in the gem install error message did not contain /opt/local/bin, which got removed because of rvm's installation games with .bash_profile, which is where macports put the addition of /opt/local/bin to the PATH)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't quite the answer to the question, but the recommended way of installing Imagemagick and Rmagick on Mac is through [homebrew](https://brew.sh/). It's the only way I could get Imagemagick and Rmagick playing nicely together on Mac.

Answer (score 35):

command: `sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu (11.10+) try installing the libmagick++-dev package.

For other Linux distributions, try installing the libmagick-dev package.

Comment: Acctually package libmagick++-dev 8:6.6.9.7-5ubuntu3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

For my case, I am installing it on Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu3, got same error, tried to installed the following two package suites and it worked, maybe either one of them:

`sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat`

`sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev`

Answer (score 2):

On mac, after

> brew install imagemagick

Don't forget to link dylibs with:

> brew link imagemagick

Answer (score 0):

I had to transfer an old application to a debian stretch server.
The used ruby version was 2.0.x.
imagemagick was installed including libmagickwand-dev.
Trying to install rmagick 2.13.2 failed.

I had to upgrade the rmagick verion (patched my Gemfile.lock) to use rmagick **2.16.0**, the last version supporting ruby 2.0.